# compare different state array in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

How to compare states in array? I can't use `!==` or use `.length`

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(props.languages !== statelanguages)) {
      return {
        languages: props.languages
      }
    }
    return null
  }
```

I can use isEqual from lodash but won't that be overkill?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how thorough your check should be. If you want to be absolutely certain that 2 arrays completely match - which means all of their elements match - then simple length or reference check will not suffice. You will need `lodash.isEqual` or something similar.

Note that `lodash.isEqual` will be very quick if `props.languages` and `statelanguages` are "reference" equal, which means if `props.languages === statelanguages` evaluates to true, it'll return true right away. If not, then it proceeds to check for length checks and deep equality checks - the last one can get costly if your array sizes are big.

Comment: That depends on your array size. How big is your array?

Comment: @Melissa, don't worry about performance optimisation until it becomes an actual problem.

Comment: You can also go for something like [react-fast-compare](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-fast-compare) or ImmutableJS but I agree with Matt - don't worry about it until you actually see performance issues.